# WebService to access data from mvnrepository.com

Tags: angular, maven, dependency-management

I'm looking for a way to access the data which is provided on this website https://mvnrepository.com/

I actually need to access the indexed artifacts. If I have the groupId and the name like this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist I wanna retrieve the information what versions exist for this library and if I have the version in addition to that I wanna know what dependencies the library has.

I am coding an angular2 app about visualization of dependencies in a software project and I wanna give additional information to libraries.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Right now I'm trying it with the REST API from the Maven Central Repository http://search.maven.org/#api But it is not working. Does anybody has a clue why?

Comment: `getSuggestionsOf(key: string){

    this.http.get("http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q="+key+"&rows=20&wt=json")

      .subscribe(

        (response) => this.mapSuggestions(response.json()),

        (error) => this.onError(error.json())

      );

}



  private mapSuggestions(json){

    console.log(json);

    for (let lib of json.response.docs) {

      console.log(lib.id);

    }

  }`

Comment: mvnrepository.com has nothing to do with Maven Central or search.maven.org. Therefore Maven Central's REST API will not work there

Comment: But isn't it providing the same data about the artifacts?

Comment: Simply No it is not...